# Ruby Selenium WebDriver: Unable to locate element in popup window

Tags: ruby

I am not able to locate any elements in a popup window. However, I can click on the pop-up. Getting this error on line 9 - `'Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"user.userName"}'`

Scenario:

1) Open http://www.harley-davidson.com/store/

2) Click on 'Sign In' link

3) Enter user name and password to login

Please help me in resolving this error.

My code:

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'

browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
browser.manage.window.maximize
wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 15)
browser.get "http://www.harley-davidson.com/store/"    
browser.find_element(id: "logonLinkDiv").click #to click on the sign-in link
wait
browser.find_element(id: "hdwcOverlay_h").click  #to click on the sign-in pop-up window

#I am unable to identify the elements 'User Name' and 'Password' in the pop-up window**

browser.find_element(id: "user.userName").send_keys("test@test.com")
browser.find_element(id: "user.password").send_keys("test123")  
browser.quit
```

Comment: Edit your post... Give us the code only. remove the line numbers.. we don't need.

Comment: Is the popup/overlay in a frame?  If so, check out the [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RubyBindings).  For example: `driver.switch_to.frame "some-frame"` under _# switch to a frame_.

Comment: sorry guys...I am new to this forum and just a beginner in Ruby. I will not repeat this in my future posts.

Answer (score 0):

As @orde mentioned, you need to switch to the correct frame, because frames are treated as whole separate documents with their own DOM. Looking at the page you linked to, this should work:

```
driver.switch_to.frame "hdwcOverlayIframe" # do this first
# now these should work
browser.find_element(id: "user.userName").send_keys("test@test.com")
browser.find_element(id: "user.password").send_keys("test123")
```